# sort string data based on len and int

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list with dictionaries as below, I want to sort data based on 'd' as string in sorting order.

```
src_dict_list=[{'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-22'}, 
               {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-18'},
               {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-11144'},
               {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-11146'},
               {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-11149'},
               {'a':'a1','b':'b1','c':'c1','d':'1000-11148'}]
```

here d values are considered as string so I tried with len but I want data to sorted as per numeric values as well.

Code:

```
print(sorted(src_dict_list,key=lambda k:len(k['d'])))
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-22'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-18'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11144'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11146'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11149'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11148'}]
```

Expected:

```
[{'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-18'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-22'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11144'}, 
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11146'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11148'},
 {'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1', 'c': 'c1', 'd': '1000-11149'}]
```

can you please help me?

Comment: What exactly *is* the "numeric value" of "1000-22"?

Comment: @deceze. I assumed it's natsort order, but good question

Comment: What does length have to do with it if you want numeric order?

Comment: Simply it fix the need. sorter = lambda k : list(map(int,k['d'].split('-')))
print(sorted(src_dict_list,key=sorter))

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to sort based on the lexical ordering of the integers in the string of d. Something like:

```
sorter = lambda k : list(map(int,k['d'].split('-')))
print(sorted(src_dict_list,key=sorter))
```

Comment: But 'd' value might come in different format also like '1000-00-18','1000-0100-00-18', with out splitting the data, is there any other generic way?

Comment: I am not following how you want them sorted. Do you want the '1000-00-18' first or the '1000-0100-00-18' first? You have some idea of sorting you want, but your not telling us. What are your rules for sorting?

Comment: my requirement is 2 ways, 1) if it is integer we can directly convert it to int and sort it dictly. we are aware of this. 2) if it is a string having some special characters in 'd' like '-','*' etc, but data should be sorted like integers only.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the '-' and '*'? That is int(k['d'].replace('-','').replace('*','')) and make it one big integer?

Comment: In simply do this. sorter = lambda k : list(map(int,k['d'].split('-')))
print(sorted(src_dict_list,key=sorter))

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that you want your `key` function to be something like:

```
lambda k: tuple(map(int, k['d'].split('-')))
```

This turns `"1000-18"` into `(1000, 18)`, i.e. a tuple of ints. That will sort by the numeric value of `1000` primarily and on equality by `18` secondarily.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by both the 2 values of `d`, so first by the 1000 here, then for each 1000, by the second value. For multiple criterias you need to provide a tuple/list  in the `key`, for `1000-18` we would need `(1000, 18)` (as `int values)`

So for one value you'd like to operate `tuple(map(int,k['d'].split('-')))`

Giving

```
sorted(src_dict_list, key=lambda k:tuple(map(int,k['d'].split('-'))))
```